# Slow performance while copying large files to external peripherals

Tags: performance, usb-drive, external-hdd

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10, I have been having many problems with External Storage devices like Hard Disk and pen drives.

Sometimes, my external HDD (WD Passport 500 GB) is not detected at all, and any files I am transferring that are more than 1 GB stop in the middle or slow down so much that it takes 2 hours just to transfer a file of 2.9 GB.

I am facing the same problem with my pen drive if I try to transfer files above 700 MB. I have already disabled all password requirements for my HDD and still doesn't get detected regularly.

Comment: those are two questions. You should split them. Let's concentrate on the external HDD problem. Are you using a front panel USB port? Also what file system do you have on the HDD?